# React Router not creating route after reactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to code an app using ReactJS which includes creating routes based on user input. Here is my current code:

index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';


class Renders extends Component {
state = {routesList : ["testRoute", "testRoute2"]};

addRoute = (route, category) => {
this.setState(previousState => ({
routesList: [...previousState.routesList, route]
}), console.log(this.state.routesList));
}

render() {
return(<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<App callBackFunction={this.addRoute}/>} />
{this.state.routesList.map((routePoint) => <Route path={["/", routePoint].join("")} element={<p>This route is /{routePoint}</p>}/>)}
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>)
}
};

ReactDOM.render(
<Renders/>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

components/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  state = {questions: {}, requested: false, isPlaying: false, isCreate: false};

  render() {
    this.getQuestions();
    return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.callBackFunction("route3", "")}>Create link</button> 
    </div>);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Details:

```
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
```

I expected that when the button was clicked, a route `/route3` would be created and opening that route in the browser would show: `This route is /route3`. Instead, I received a warning saying:
`No routes matched location "/route3"` Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. See this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-not-creating-route-after-reactdom-render-b4tgw5?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks for the codesandbox! It worked perfectly. I guess it was just a miscellaneous minor code error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Cheers and good luck!